# What's happening on Windows 10 when trying to shut down, which takes more than one hour?

Tags: windows-10, shutdown

When I shutdown update might be loaded and installed, which cost time. This is understandable. But sometimes when I shut down it takes a huge amount of time, even more then one hour. I run as a administrator but sometime also as a normal user.

I get the message:

> Someone else  is still using this PC. If you shut down now, they could lose unsaved work."

With the button: "Shutdown anyway".

I am the only user and I checked that in the taskmanager. Also in the taskmanager no app is active. Even the processes are limited, less than 10%.

I want to know what is happening on my computer. There is no need to use so much time. I rarely use Windows, mostly Ubuntu, with Ubuntu shut down is just fast shutdown, as it should be.

Answer (score 0):

I would try run Windows Performance Recorder which is part of the ADK, it should give you a trace of what is happening with your system linked [HERE](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/test/wpt/windows-performance-recorder)

I would also check the event logs, the event log service should still be running at this time.

Comment: The Windows performance Recorder I have to start and stop manual. And I do not know in advanced what will happen. The "Event viewer" is more valuable, thank you for that. I can see that most the "Microsoft Windows security auditing" is used. In the task manager the resources CPU and Disk are hardly used. But memory is, by the "Antimalware Executable" This seems to point in the same direction. But even after two hours I can not shutdown Windows 10 without getting the message that an other user is using my computer.